# Arch-Win7 dual boot laptop freezes, and then is unable to boot

Tags: boot, bootloader, gpt

I have a Dell Precision laptop, with a Arch-Windows 7 dual boot, 64bits systems, GRUB2 as boot loader, and a single SSD.

I found myself browsing around for reasons which I will not explain to [this](http://www.atnoc.net/) page, which I tried to google translate. The system, for reasons unknown, freezed. I tried to fire task manager but it thrown an error (I don't remember the exact error), and then a scary blue screen appeared.
I hard rebooted the system, and from that point the laptop wasn't able to boot anymore. Not even the GRUB appeared: I just got the "please insert bootable device" error.

I managed to boot with an ubuntu live USB. From ubuntu I used `fdisk -l` and found out that while the SSD was detected, the partition table was given as corrupted.

Fortunately, [testdisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) was still able to detect the partitions. Using it I magened to kind of recover the partitions. With this I mean that for example `lsblk` and `fdisk` show the partition and I was able to mount them.

I tried to repair the partition table with `testdisk`, and then with `gdisk`, but nothing. Booting from a gparted live distribution I can see with gparted the (seemingly) correct partition scheme, i.e.:

```
Partizione  File System Etichetta   Dimensione  Usato       Libero      Flag
/dev/sda1   fat16               39.19 MiB   217 KiB     38.98 MiB   Boot
/dev/sda2   ntfs        RECOVERY    11.73 GiB   9.78 GiB    1.96 GiB
/dev/sda3   ntfs        OS      187.63 GiB  ---     ---
/dev/sda4   extended            39.07 GiB   ---     ---     lba
 |
 -> /dev/sda5   ext4                39.07 GiB   16.14 GiB   22.93 GiB
```

with a warning on /dev/sda3 from gparted which says to not be able to read the partition possibly due to the lack of ntfs packages.

What is happening? And how can I recover from this situation?

Answer (score 2):

The boot partition (fat16) is small - only 39 MB. This can create problems.

You could try to fix only MBR and boot records and see if this would be enough to boot Windows 7.

Rewrite **MBR** and **boot record of sda1(boot partition) to Windows 7 format** (NT6 format) using a Linux live CD/USB (testdisk can write boot records).

Usually for fixing Windows 7 boot problems you need a Windows 7 installation/recovery USB/DVD - see [here](http://www.boyans.net/RepairWindows/repair-windows-boot.html) how to proceed.

After you have fixed Windows 7 booting you can go on and fix ARCH (GRUB2) booting using a Linux live USB/DVD.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  How large should the boot partition be? Also, I'm not sure if you're suggesting to try to fix the problem with testdisk or with a Windows installation disk

Comment: Boot partition(Microsoft names it "system partition" - where boot files are) is usually 100-500MB. Any tool that can write MBR and PBR to Windows 7 format (if you have Windows 7 use bootsect.exe - would be best). MOVING OR RESIZING PARTITIONS CAUSES BOOT PROBLEMS!!! (Then you have to fix boot manager/loader with bcdboot.exe)